# How to connect to cosmosdb emulator from firefox OSX outside of VM?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I have followed these instructions for setting up the cosmosdb local emulator. [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli%2Cssl-netstd21#export-the-ssl-certificate). My use case is not covered there. I want to view the cosmosdb emulator start page outside the VM on firefox. Inside the VM it is located at: https://10.0.2.15:8081/_explorer/index.html. I started the emulator with the /AllowNetworkAccess /NoFirewall flags. Furthermore I disabled TLS/SSL in firefox by doing it in the about:config section. I still cannot view the index.html file from outside the VM. How do I configure this so I can view the cosmosdb emulator index.html file from outside the VM on firefox running on OSX? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show which SDK and language you are trying to use and which is your current attempt?

Comment: Im not connecting to it with an SDK/programming language. I have setup virtual box with a windows VM. I have installed cosmosdb emulator in that. I can start up the emulator and navigate to its index.html page within the VM itself. Outside of the VM index.html page is not accessible and I want to find out why that is and how to fix it.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I decided to go with the documentation. I am now using the nodejs SDK and have followed the instructions. I still get a timeout. the http request never resolves. I have put the code here, if you want to take a look and help me out. Thanks. https://github.com/danielptm/node_example/blob/master/app.js

Comment: HTTP timeouts might mean your VM is simply not exposing the ports out to receive the request from the other machine. Normally you need to map the internal port (8081) to some external port and make sure the IP you are connecting to, is the public IP for the VM. I can't think of anything else if that's already done.